# How to get success status of last Bash shell command inside a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, error-handling

Sometimes there are two commands which I often invoke in a row. However the second command only makes sense in case the first command was successful.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $? -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "WARNING: previous command entered at the shell prompt failed"
fi
```

But it doesn't work:

```
t@quad:~$ echo "abc" | grep def
t@quad:~$ ./warnme.sh 
Last command succeeded
```

What I'd like is something a bit like this:

```
t@quad:~$ echo "abc" | grep def
t@quad:~$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
1
```

Where we can clearly see that the last command failed.

The result I'd like to have:

```
t@quad:~$ echo "abc" | grep def
t@quad:~$ ./warnme.sh 
WARNING: previous command entered at the shell prompt failed
```

I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: A shell script is an entirely new shell, so a new call. Do you need it as a separate shell script, or is defining a function or an alias in your bashrc enough?

Comment: @Wrikken: I'd need it as a shell script. Is there a way, given the parent shell's PID (which is accessible), to access the parent shell's $? variable (the one holding the result of the last command?).  Maybe this should be a new question?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no.. You could add your requirement that it should be a shell script to your question explicitly, maybe someone more knowledgeable knows something, but I'm afraid the answer will be there is no practical way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
command1 && command2
```

does exactly what you want: command 2 is executed only if command1 succeeds. For example you could do:

```
ls a.out && ./a.out
```

Then a.out would only be executed if it could be listed. I wikiblogged about this at http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/%26%26

Answer (score 2):

One option is to put this just before the list of commands you want to execute only if the previous was successful:

```
set -e
```

This will exit the script if any of the commands following it return non-zero (usually a fail).  You can switch it off again with:

```
set +e
```

Or if you'd prefer to switch it off for just one line you can just logical-OR the command with true:

```
mycommand || true
```

For a lot of my scripts I have set -e at the top of the script as a safety feature to prevent the script cascading and doing something dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
echo "abc" | grep def || ./warnme.sh
```

Where warnme.sh is now only the warning without the test. It's only called if the first command fails.

In other words, it would be the same as:

```
echo "abc" | grep def || echo "WARNING: That didn't work..."
```